# How to pass an array String data as argument?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

So, my question is you know how we are able to pass String as argument to a method
by just doing method("This","are","Strings");

How can you do this with an array of String
when the method is supposed to hold a array.
I know that you cant do this method({"This","is","an","array"});
Is there any way of doing something similar?
And thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just intialize an array of strings and pass it:

```
method(new String[]{"This", "is", "an", "array"});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use varargs:

```
public void method(String... values) {
    //...
}

method("Hello", "World");
```

Comment: Or, if the method must take an array, method(new String[] {"Hello", "World"});

Comment: Well, varargs is an array. If it must be an array literal then just `new String[] {}`, but that'd be no different than having the array initialized before.

Comment: He might be unable to change method's argument list though.

Answer (score 0):

You can send array of strings like below.

```
method(String[] arr){}
```

and call that method with string array as argument.

```
String array = new String[]{"value1","value2"};
method(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this can take an optional list of strings and also you need to make it the last argument and mention other before.

```
private void method(String... values){
        for (String s : values){

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
public static void arrayString(String[] params) 
{
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(params));
}
```

While calling call it as

```
arrayString(new String[]{"This","is","an","array"});
```